# How do I use apt-get to install one update at a time?

Tags: security, apt, ubuntu-16.04, update

I have inherited 15 servers running Ubuntu 16.04 and need to install security updates on them all.

I have been told by my manager to install them one at a time and then test the system to make sure nothing has broken before installing the next one. I know this is a slow process but we have had problems with updates in the past so this is a belt and braces approach.

I know that I can do the whole lot in one go with the commands sudo apt-get update and then sudo apt-get upgrade.

Is there a way that i can install only one upgrade at at time?

Answer (score 2):

You should always install an upgrade with its dependencies.

First run

```
apt-get update
```

Then ask a list of available upgrades

```
apt-get -u upgrade --assume-no
```

Choose a package to upgrade, and run

```
apt-get install XXXX
```

The package and its dependencies will be installed.  Run your tests, when done, ask for a new list and continue until finished.

Answer (score 0):

Using bash:

```bash
vars="package1 package2 package3"
for x in $vars; do
  sudo apt --only-upgrade install $x
  sudo apt clean
done
```

Answer (score 0):

To build upon @Richard's answer, a one liner to update all system packages one at a time:

```
for x in `sudo apt list --upgradable | cut -d / -f 1`; do sudo apt --only-upgrade -y install $x && sudo apt clean; done
```